# Create a checkerboard using only recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a homework like this:
Create a function called checkerboard using recursion which, given a size argument, will draw an n by n checkerboard on the screen.  Example: checkerboard(5)

```
* * * * *
 * * * * *
* * * * *
 * * * * *
* * * * *
```

I have done this:

```
const star = function (n) {
  if (n === 0)
    return "";

  return "*" + star(n-1);
};

const space = function (n) {
  if (n === 0)
    return "";

  return " " + space(n-1);
};

const printer1 = function(n) {
  if  (n===0) {
    return "";
  }
  return (star(1) + space(1) + printer1(n-1));
}

printer1(5);
```

But I cannot go further, because when I want to add a new function typing the space first and then the stars and so on, the log outputs only the first function (printer1). So please help, any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What functions are acceptable for use? You said no to slice which is a pretty big one.

Comment: Isn’t it possible to use sheer functional programming with recursion abd without any built-in tunction?

Comment: You say you need to write an n x n checkerboard, but your example with n = 5 shows a 10 x 5 checkerboard. A 5 x 5 board would have three asterisks and two spaces in the first row. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion for this you can use `Array.from()` and `String.repeat()`

```js
let printer1 = function(n) {
  return Array.from(Array(n), (e, i) => (i % 2 != 0 ? ' ' : '') + '* '.repeat(n).slice(0, -1)).join('\n')
}

console.log(printer1(5))
console.log(printer1(11))
```

Here is similar solution using recursion.

```js
let printer1 = function(n, i = 0) {
  var r = '';
  if(i == n) return r;
  r = (i % 2 != 0 ? ' ' : '') + '* '.repeat(n).slice(0, -1) + '\n' + printer1(n, i+1)
  return r
}

console.log(printer1(5))
console.log(printer1(11))
```

Here is pure recursive solution.

```js
let printer1 = function(n, i = 0) {
  let r = '', space = i % 2 != 0 ? ' ' : ''
  if(n == i) return r;
  return r += space + row(n) + '\n' + printer1(n, i + 1)
}

let row = function(n, j = 0)  {
  let r = '', sign = j < n - 1 ? '* ' : '*';
  if(n == j) return r;
  return r += sign + row(n, j + 1);
}

console.log(printer1(5))
console.log(printer1(11))
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but as I stated we should use only recursion

Comment: if you can solve this problem using recursion, I would be very grateful

Comment: Isn’t there any simple way to do it without using existing functions like repeat and slice?

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkerboard = function(lineCount, collection, itemCount){
    var joiner = function(count, item, delimiter){
        return Array(count).fill().map(()=>item).join(delimiter)
    }
    collection = collection || []
    if (itemCount === undefined){
        itemCount = lineCount
    }
    if (lineCount === 0) {
        return collection.join('\n');
    }
    if (collection.length % 2 === 0) {
        collection.push(joiner(itemCount, '*', ' '))
    } else {
        collection.push(joiner(itemCount, ' ', '*'))
    }
    return checkerboard(lineCount - 1, collection, itemCount)
}

console.log(checkerboard(5))
console.log(checkerboard(11))
```

Comment: Good, but you know it is only the beginning of the class intro to computer science and it is meant that we dont know such complex things

Answer (score 0):

**you're off to a great start**

Here's a technique that uses nothing other than user-defined functions and the arguments they're applied to – built-ins like `Array.from`, `Array.fill`, `String.repeat`, `Array.prototype.join`, are avoided because they don't actually teach you anything at this level – we *do* use binary operator `+` for string concatenation tho, and binary operator `-` to decrement a counter.

This is not too far off from your own code, which I think you will appreciate. You can *see* everything that's happening here, which matters more than how well it performs. As a student, this visibility of your functions allows you to imagine the process the interpreter will evolve as your program is running; a critical skill at any point along your learning journey

Later, when you are exposed to other features or built-in functions in your language, *then* you can evaluate whether those provide a benefit to your programs in particular situations – for now tho, functions and arguments; rinse; <s>repeat</s> recur ^_^

```js
const board = (size, cells) =>
  {
    const loop = (acc, line, [c, ...cs]) =>
      line === 0
        ? acc
        : loop (acc + c (size) + '\n', line - 1, [...cs, c])
    return loop ('', size, cells)
  }
  
const cell = str => size =>
  size === 0
    ? ''
    : str + cell (str) (size - 1)

const black =
  cell ('* ')

const white =
  cell (' *')
        
console.log (board (7, [black, white]))
```

of course since board accepts an *array* of cells, we can have any number of variety

```js
const board = (size, cells) =>
  {
    const loop = (acc, line, [c, ...cs]) =>
      line === 0
        ? acc
        : loop (acc + c (size) + '\n', line - 1, [...cs, c])
    return loop ('', size, cells)
  }
  
const cell = str => size =>
  size === 0
    ? ''
    : str + cell (str) (size - 1)

const black =
  cell ('* ')

const white =
  cell (' *')
  
const third =
  cell ('# ')

const fourth =
  cell (' @')
        
console.log (board (8, [black, white, third, fourth]))
// * * * * * * * * 
//  * * * * * * * *
// # # # # # # # # 
//  @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
// * * * * * * * * 
//  * * * * * * * *
// # # # # # # # # 
//  @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @
```